# SVN pre-revprop-change hook for not allowing edited log messages to be less than 10 characters

Tags: batch-file, svn, cmd

In this is a pre-revprop-change hook, what do I have to add to it so that it does not allow edited log messages to be less than 10 characters?

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Set all parameters. Even though most are not used, in case you want to add
:: changes that allow, for example, editing of the author or addition of log messages.

set repository=%1
set revision=%2
set userName=%3
set propertyName=%4
set action=%5

:: Only allow the log message to be changed, but not author, etc.
if /I not "%propertyName%" == "svn:log" goto ERROR_PROPNAME

:: Only allow modification of a log message, not addition or deletion.
if /I not "%action%" == "M" goto ERROR_ACTION

:: Make sure that the new svn:log message is not empty.
set bIsEmpty=true
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('find /V ""') do (
set bIsEmpty=false
)
if "%bIsEmpty%" == "true" goto ERROR_EMPTY

goto :eof

:ERROR_EMPTY
echo Empty svn:log messages are not allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_PROPNAME
echo Only changes to svn:log messages are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_ACTION
echo Only modifications to svn:log revision properties are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1
```

I've tried adding a counter setting the count to 0 initially like:

```
:: Make sure that the new svn:log message is not empty.
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('find /V ""') do (
set "count=count+1"
)

if %count% lss 10 goto ERROR_EMPTY
```

but somehow this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: side note: avoid assigning environment variable `UserName` as such is predefined by the Windows OS...

Comment: 1. you are parsing the output of `find /V ""`, but you did not specify _where_ the search string should be found; 2. `for /F "tokens=*"` iterates through _lines_ of text, not _characters_; 3. you could use something like `if "%MSG%"=="%MSG:~,9%", which will fail in case `MSG` contains a string with 10 or more characters;